# How can I create cakephp 3 custom template

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new in cakephp 3.

I want to create form helper that will generate code like this.

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" required="">
        </div>
</div>
```

I am using this

```
<?php 
        $myTemplates = [
            'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group">{{label}}<div class="col-sm-9">{{input}}</div></div>',
            'inputContainerError' => '<div class="input {{class}} {{type}}{{required}} error">{{content}}{{error}}</div>'
        ];
    ?>
    <?= $this->Form->create('Users',['templates' => $myTemplates]) ?>                       
    <?= $this->Form->input('email',['class' => 'form-control','templates' => ['formGroup' => '{{input}}{{label}}']]) ?>
```

But it will generate wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create Template code

```
<?php $myTemplates = [
'label' => '<label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{text}}</label>',
'select' => '<div class="col-sm-9"><select class="form-control" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select></div>',
'input' => '<div class="col-sm-9"><input class="form-control" type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}></div>',
'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-control">{{content}}</div>',
'inputSubmit' => '<input type="{{type}}"{{attrs}}>',
'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group row">{{content}}</div>',
'submitContainer' => '<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">&nbsp;</label><div class="col-sm-9 ">{{content}}</div></div>',
]; ?>
```

Now Use this template code inside in form

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create($schoolAccount); ?>  
<?php $this->Form->setTemplates($myTemplates); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->control('account_holder',['label'=>'Name of Account Holder']); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Per the docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses) - to change theme inline at runtime use `setTemplate`:

```
$myTemplates = [
    'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group">{{label}}<div class="col-sm-9">{{input}}</div></div>',
    'inputContainerError' => '<div class="input {{class}} {{type}}{{required}} error">{{content}}{{error}}</div>'
];
?>
<?= $this->Form->create('Users') ?>
<? $this->Form->setTemplates($myTemplates); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('email',['class' => 'form-control','templates' => ['formGroup' => '{{input}}{{label}}']]) ?>
```

You can't use the `templates` option on the Form for a dynamic template, it will only look for a config file listing template items in `/config`.

Comment: It is not working, I have used same code.It will generate error